I messed up installing a large curtain rod and made these holes in the drywall too large for my self-drilling anchors. How should I resolve this?
https://imgur.com/a/bPEGdrm
These holes are just larger than 1/2 inch and the anchors I have are now loose. I went to the hardware store to find a larger version of the anchor I have but there are no larger ones.
It seems that my next option is to use a toggle anchor? Is this the recommended approach? The metal or plastic ones? Should I try filling in these holes with something, letting it dry, and try again? Should I try installing the loose anchors I have again but with some sort of adhesive or putty to harden?
This is my first time doing this and the drapes I’m putting up are a bit on the heavier side so I need something durable.

Why did you make holes for self drilling anchors?   Anyway ... no shame, this is how we all learned.  Don't patch and re-do.  If these drapes are purely decorative you can use toggle anchors.   If they will be handled by human hands, IE opened and closed, you should find studs and mount to those.  If they have cords to open and close them you must find studs.

Toggle bolts are the only option to reuse those holes.
Heavy drapes plus the possibility of being pulled on, mounting to close by studs would be recommended.
Since you already have the holes, stick an inspection camera or stiff wire in to locate studs.
